# How to convert milliseconds to current date?

Tags: javascript

I have number of milliseconds

```
43200000 -> 12:00
```

its number of milliseconds in hours.

I need to convert it to current Date, but its converting to 1970th?

How can I tie it with current Date?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]) ). We cant help you with code problems when you are not disclosing your code. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
function msToTime(duration) {
  var today = new Date();
  var arr=[];
  var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = parseInt((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = parseInt((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;


  var myToday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), hours, minutes, seconds);


  arr.push(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds);
  arr.push(myToday);
 return arr;
}
console.log(msToTime(43200000));
```

Result:

```
arr[0]:"12:00:00.0"
arr[1]:Thu Sep 06 2018 12:00:00 GMT+0200
```

**Demo**: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/txd0b7ok/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have example:

```
var time = new Date().getTime();
var date = new Date(time);
alert(date.toString()); // D MM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

if you already have a string, convert it explicitly:

```
date = parseInt(date);
```

Other example, could be use datejs and convert in different format. let's see:

```
var d = new Date(1469433907836);

d.toLocaleString()     // MM/DD/YYYY, H:MM:SS PM
d.toLocaleDateString() // MM/DD/YYYY
d.toDateString()       // D MM DD YYYY
d.toTimeString()       // HH:MM:SS GMT
d.toLocaleTimeString() // HH:MM:SS PM
```

For more information about that you can see [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/FormatSpecifiers.wiki)